# GSON + HTC Desire: Conflict. Possible solution jarjar.jar causes error

Tags: gson, android, jarjar

I am trying to use GSON in Android app but it causes a crash. After some reading it seems that HTC have included GSON and that causes a conflict. One propoused solution was to use jarjar.jar to rename gson classes to solve the conflict. When I try to do this I get this error:

Syntax error: Error on line 1: [{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360]

The command I am executing:

java -jar jarjar-1.2.jar process rules.txt gson-2.1.jar myjson-2.1.jar

rules.txt:
rule com.google.gson.** com.google.myjson.@1

Any ideas?

Comment: I have used GSon with HTC Desire, Nexus One, Wildfire and Wildfire S, HTC Evo and many others. None of them had any conflict. How do you include the library, what problem are you faced with?

Comment: It's a known bug. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=255 But I haven't seen that syntax error. Which program is reporting it?

Comment: I am facing problems with GSON on Desire HD (2.3.5). In my case unfortunatelly I cannot use jarajar because gson is used by 3rd party library and I have no control on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no problems using GSON, on any phone. Which problems are you facing?

Besides, it would seem that the rules.txt file you are passing is actually a RTF file. If you are using a Mac, try to save it again as a plain text file.